# nginx.service is not starting after mount

Tags: nginx, systemd, systemd-service

I have a nginx that depends on a mounted drive.

My nginx.service has an entry with the RequiresMountsFor in the service unit like this:

```
[Unit]
RequiresMountsFor=/media/bar
```

But looks like it is still booting ahead of the mount point.

My mount cmd looks like this and on cron jobs @reboot:

```
mount -o bg,nolock,noac,actimeo=0 192.168.1.5:/foo/bar /media/bar
```

I'm not finding where it is going wrong. Here is config showing `systemctl show nginx.service`

```
...
Before=multi-user.target shutdown.target
After=foo-bar.mount sysinit.target network.target -.mount system.slice basic.target systemd-journald.socket
RequiresMountsFor=/media/bar
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run specifically after cron, you may be able to add

```
Requires=cronie.service
```

in your unit file, which will wait for crond to start before trying the nginx service.

You may also have some luck moving the mount to `/etc/fstab` instead of as a cron. systemd automatically picks up mounts from there and creates appropriate mount files.